# UIActivityIndicatorView doesn't stop for UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

**EDIT: I SOLVED IT**

I solved it.
I changed:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

to

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

**MY QUESTION:**

I am making a simple UIWebView app and I want the indicator to stop spinning when it is done loading the webpage. I checked "hide when done" in the storyboarding interface and I have connected the indicator to the view controller (activityIndicator). It still doesn't stop. In my header file, I have this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>{
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *bBack, *bForward, *toolbarStop, *toolbarRefresh;
IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *_activityIndicator;

BOOL internetOK;
NSTimer *timer;

}
-(void)tryInternet;
-(void)loading;
-(void)startAnimating;
-(void)stopAnimating;
-(void)verifyInternet;
-(IBAction)refresh:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)dontTouchMe:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)refreshWebView:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

And in my .m file, I have this:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Why doesn't this work? Do you have any ideas?

Comment: did u connect delegate to your webView ?

Comment: @amitsoni is correct If you have not set UIWebView delegate then - - (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView and (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView will not work.

Comment: Do you mean connecting UIWebView to the activity indicator? I did that, doesn't work.

Comment: Connect the UIWebView delegate to the File's owner

Comment: @Zen Do you mean the View Controller? FIle's owner doesn't exist in Xcode 4. If so, I already did that. The web view wouldn't work without doing that.

Comment: webview will work without using delegate but webview delegate method will not work if u want to try try it load any url without using its delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I changed:

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

to

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it using following code.

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
 [_activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
 [_activityIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 20, 20)];
 [self.view addSubview:_activityIndicator];
 [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
 [_activityIndicator startAnimating];
}
```

I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

in your .h file, take both names same, i.e. activityIndicator.
Then in your .m file synthesize it, i.e `activityIndicator = _activityIndicator`.
And then write the following code -

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
 [activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
 [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
 [activityIndicator stopAnimating]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, you have connect delegate to your view controller.

And whenever `webViewDidStartLoad` delegate of `UIWebView` called, your animation starts.

I think that, instead of `webViewDidFinishLoad` method, `webViewFailedToLoad` method is calling. So, you need to write your code `[activityIndicator stopAnimating];` inside that failed method.

Hope, it will be helpful to you.

Cheers!